# Why is my github pages site not loading my images

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I created a Github Pages website for my portfolio, and the images and not working. It is displaying the alt text. Locally everything works, and the images are in the repository, I don't know why it isn't working.
Here is the repository - https://github.com/Koolmale/koolmale.github.io
Here is the site - https://koolmale.github.io/

Comment: `Images` !== `images`. Files are case sensitive. Also, for the sake of consistency I would rename your files to have no spaces or other non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: what do you mean? I use a capital I to show the file path to the image

Comment: You're hosting the images is a folder called `Images` (uppercase `I`) and trying to access them with `images/....` (lowercase `I`)